# apache You don't have permission to access (ubuntu amazon ec2)

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've created and installed Apache on amazon EC2 few times before.

But this time I cannot seems to get apache to run the code that I put on a Volume I created and mounted on /data1/

I use the following  000-default.conf in my /etc/apache2/sites-available that is already enabled

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        RewriteEngine On

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html/web
        DocumentRoot /data1/proj/ba/web

   <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

        <Directory  /data1/proj/ba/web>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

And I get http://ec2-54-197-1-250.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at
>   ec2-54-197-1-250.compute-1.amazonaws.com Port 80

I tried

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /data1/proj
sudo chmod -R g+rw /data1/proj
```

and also other variation of these cmds

Now the strange thing is that if I change the DocumentRoot to /var/www/html/web
and create a symlink `sudo ln -s /data1/proj/ba/web/ /var/www/html/web`

than it is working! this is ok for now but in the future it might be a problem for me.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

here is the new format:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName myproj.co.il
        ServerAlias www.myproj.co.il
        RewriteEngine On

        ExpiresActive On

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log vhost_combined

        DocumentRoot /data1/projects/myproj/
        <Directory  /data1/projects/myproj/>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
               AllowOverride All
               Require all granted


               <FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png|js|css)$">
                        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

            </FilesMatch>

        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Note the `Require all granted` line that replaced the

```
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
```